# Clang runtime checks: print backtrace

Tags: c++, c, runtime, clang, ubsan

Clang compiler provides a number of useful runtime checks, like e.g. [`-fsanitize=unsigned-integer-overflow`](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#controlling-code-generation). Can I print a backtrace (e.g. using gdb) when one of the checks fails? Currently I get the exact location of the problem, but I do not have the context. How could I get more information from these runtime checks, especially the backtrace?

Answer (score 4):

An easier solution which does not require enabling fatal errors is to set env. variable `UBSAN_OPTIONS=print_stacktrace=1`.

Answer (score 0):

The program can be made to abort using these flags:

```
-fsanitize=undefined-trap -fsanitize-undefined-trap-on-error -ftrap-function=abort
```

The last option causes abort to be invoked; you can run the program under GDB and print the backtrace after the program aborts.

Source - [answer to "Will any programs detect a buffer overflow within a C/C++ structure?"](/a/8497859)

Comment: Using abort may be quite inefficient for large apps as you dramatically increase the latency to fix a single bug (you have to go through lengthy detect-fix-rebuild-deploy-test cycle for each bug).

Comment: But in GDB you can go up the call stack to the abort, `finish` the function and `signal 0` to continue.  That said, if you're finding that many issues in your code at this stage, you probably need to be looking for problems in your unit tests, code review and the rest of your development process.

Comment: Oh yeah, go tell this to developers next time you get a task to sanitize full Linux distro and report your findings.